# Using a varchar primary key in a status table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Preamble: I know there are many topics about Varchar primary keys. I have read those. This question is slightly different in that I want to use it only on a Status table.

I always use int primary keys on tables.

However, I have found an edge case where it might actually be better to use a varchar or char column instead.

The edge case is in a "Status" table.  For example, an Order might have a status of OPEN or FULFILLED.  So my status table would only hold two rows.

In writing a query, I would rather write: Select * from orders where Status = 'OPEN'

then write: Select * from orders where StatusId = 1;//

Does this makes sense?  Am I missing anything?  I am a javascript dev, not an sql guy, so I am taking baby steps here.

The only disadvantage I can see is that it would take up slightly more space in the Orders table, and the join might be slightly slower.  But the payoff in readability seems significant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are usually reasonable exceptions to rules that purists suggest (except for the use of commas in the `FROM` clause ;)

I tend to be a purist when it comes to primary keys on tables, wanting all of them to be auto-incremented integers.  These have numerous advantages, such as:

- They are more efficient in indexes.
- Attributes of the keys can be changed without changing existing code.
- Foreign key references guarantee the accuracy of the data.

For your simple example, the only downside I can readily see is the second.  If someone comes along and wants to change "OPEN" to "OPENED", they can't.  This is probably a very minor consideration, given that status values are actually unlikely to change in the future.  It is unlikely that an index would consist only of the status (unless you have a bunch more values).  Also, for the number of values you have, you could use a `tinyint` for the table key, and that would save a bit of space in each record.

By the way, using a reference table for this purpose is most useful if the `status` might appear in more than on table.  Otherwise, you can use a check constraint:

```
constraint chk_status check (status in ('OPEN', 'FULFILLED'))
```

I would not recommend this if multiple tables share the same status.